# Remove telephone numbers in a string masked with many spaces in PHP

Tags: php, string, number-formatting, phone-number

I wont to remove or mask a telephone number in a string, it wold be easy if the number is written without any spaces but sometimes i have something like this:

> "M name is mike and my phone is 1 2  3 4     5 6 7  8 9"

the output should be like:

> "My name is mike and my phone is *******89"

Comment: so use a method to first get rid of the spaces; there are many

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx for replace spaces

PHP Function used: `preg_replace`, `str_pad`, `strlen`, `substr`

```
$string = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9';
$string = preg_replace("/\s*/", "", $string ); //use preg_replace to replace spaces
$string = str_pad('', strlen($string)-2, '*') . substr($string, -2); // replace all without the 2 last chars with '*' and concatenate last 2 chars
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work for me because in the output i need alla other characters